# How to update tags in packagist?

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I'm the owner of the package https://packagist.org/packages/lenny4/doctrine-merge-persistent-collection-bundle

When I look at the tag of my package I got this:
[image]

`Lenny4` and `doctrine-merge-persistent-collection-bundle` where can I add/remove/update these tags ?

Comment: Perhaps [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit for this question

Comment: where are you repos hosted? with github you will need to add tags. (`git tag -a 1.2.3 -m "Updates"` and push those tags to github. If you use vscode and the github plug in those tags are not automatically included you will have to set `"git.followTagsWhenSync": true,` in your settings. I this fits your problem I will add an answer.

Comment: @theking2 tags from the **repository** are neccessary for new versions of a package. The tag list within the package's description is not synchronized to these tags

Comment: @NicoHaase im confused. If i assume correctly that the setting will force a `git push --follow-tags` this would push the tags upstream wouldn't it? Or do you need a `push.followTags` in config?

Comment: The tags you are talking about are git tags, and those define versions. The screenshot shows something different, the tags taken from the composer.json. I've edited my answer for some more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of tags is taken from your [`composer.json`](https://github.com/Lenny4/doctrine-merge-persistent-collection-bundle/blob/main/composer.json), specifically from the list of keywords you've defined in there.

Keep in mind that this is something different than a tag in your git repository. On creating one of these, you would create a new version of your package, which appears in the right sidebar on packagist.org, not in the description box on the left side.